# Combine Multiple Select Count Queries on same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a bunch of order rows in it.  I need to check the table to see if there's 1 or more rows matching 2 WHERE clauses.  If there is, I set a variable to 'yes' that I use elsewhere on the page.

Currently I'm checking this with individual php mysql queries but wondering if it's possible to combine them into a single select query so i'm hitting the database one time rather than like 10 or more times.

Here's an example of the current code:

```
$query9 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM mojave_requests where status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-BKED'";
$requestEDI = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query9));
$requestEDI = $requestEDI[num];
if ($requestEDI> 0) {
$requestsEDI = 'yes';
}

$query11 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM mojave_requests where status = 'Pending' AND local = 'LOQ53'";
$requestLOQ53 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query11));
$requestLOQ53 = $requestLOQ53[num];
if ($requestLOQ53 > 0) {
$requestsLOQ53 = 'yes';
}

$query13 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM mojave_requests where status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-YRYR'";
$requestLYRYR = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query13));
$requestLYRYR = $requestLYRYR[num];
if ($requestLYRYR > 0) {
$requestsLYRYR = 'yes';
}

$query15 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM mojave_requests where status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-CAL0611'";
$requestLCAL0611 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query15));
$requestLCAL0611 = $requestLCAL0611[num];
if ($requestLCAL0611 > 0) {
$requestsLCAL0611 = 'yes';
}
```

The only two things different between each query is the "local" column string I'm checking and the variable name I set to "Yes" if there's at least 1 match.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: have you considered using GROUP BY CLAUSE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `GROUP BY SELECT` will give you the `count` for `local` matching the values that you need:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) as num, 
         local 
FROM     mojave_requests 
WHERE    status = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY local
HAVING   local IN ('L-BKED','LOQ53','L-YRYR','L-CAL0611')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed709/1)

You should also change your PHP code and do not use those `$request___` variables, but only a while cycle to check:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    switch ($row[1]) {
      case 'L-BKED':
        code to be executed if count for L-BKED > 0
         break;
      case 'LOQ53':
        code to be executed if count for LOQ53 > 0
        break;
      case 'L-YRYR':
        code to be executed if count for L-YRYR> 0
        break;
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional sum as

```
SELECT 
sum
( 
  case when status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-BKED' then 1 else 0 end 
) as `L-BKED_COUNT`,
sum
( 
  case when status = 'Pending' AND local = 'LOQ53' then 1 else 0 end 
) as `LOQ53_COUNT`,
sum
( 
  case when status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-YRYR' then 1 else 0 end 
) as `L-YRYR_COUNT`,
sum
( 
  case when status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-CAL0611' then 1 else 0 end 
) as `L-CAL0611_COUNT`
FROM mojave_requests
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for conditional aggregation.  The simplest way to do this in MySQL is to take advantage of the fact that booleans are treated as numbers in a numeric context:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-BKED') as num_bked,
       SUM(status = 'Pending' AND local = 'LOQ53') as num_loc53,
       SUM(status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-YRYR') as num_yryr,
       SUM(status = 'Pending' AND local = 'L-CAL0611') as num_cal0611
FROM mojave_requests;
```

This returns the values in one row.  You can fetch the values by referencing the columns in php.

You can simplify this query by factoring out the first condition:

```
SELECT SUM(local = 'L-BKED') as num_bked,
       SUM(local = 'LOQ53') as num_loc53,
       SUM(local = 'L-YRYR') as num_yryr,
       SUM(local = 'L-CAL0611') as num_cal0611
FROM mojave_requests
WHERE status = 'Pending';
```

If few of the status values are actually `PENDING`, then an index on `mojave_requests(status, local)` should noticeably improve performance.